# Syntax Error with MySql Workbench and IF Statement

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm migrating from T-SQL to MySql syntax and don't know how to get over this syntax error given by Workbench 5.1.18:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `SysTicket`.`GetProductionLines` (aId INT, aActive INT, aResponsible VARCHAR(8000))
BEGIN
    IF(aId > 0) THEN SELECT * FROM ProductionLine WHERE Id = @Id;

    ELSE IF( aActive <> -1 AND aResponsible = '|$EMPTYARG$|') THEN SELECT * FROM ProductionLine;

    ELSE IF(aResponsible = '|$EMPTYARG&|') THEN SELECT * FROM ProductionLine WHERE Active = aActive;

    ELSE SELECT * FROM ProductionLine WHERE Active = aActive AND Responsible LIKE CONCAT('%', aResponsible, '%');

    END IF;    
END//
```

It says Syntax error near END (last line)
ty in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets from your IF statements for single comparisons or add commas instead of AND.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out...
The correct syntax is:

```
ELSEIF
```

instead of

```
ELSE IF
```